# How to get defined variables in Swift?

Tags: swift

Does swift have a way to access all global and scope variables that have been defined such as the get_defined_variables function in php? I am trying to target a global variable in a function by having its key name match the string sent to the function.

Comment: Nope. In general, this is a really bad idea. Use a dictionary.

Comment: `target a global variable in a function by having its key name match the string sent to the function` Every part of that seems like a bad idea ☠️

Comment: Maybe you can describe what you are trying to achieve and someone can help you with a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving by holding data in a dictionary and matching the method I wanted to run on the value in the dictionary with an enum. Thanks for the replies.